# renderAll() not working in fabric.js

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I have six floors of a building drawn on a canvas with fabric.js.  In order to show only one floor, I do this:

```
building.selectFloor = function(floorId){

    for (var i = 0; i < floors.length; i++){
        if (floorId == floors[i].name){
            floors[i].visible = true;
        }else{
            floors[i].visible = false;          
        }
    }
    canvas.renderAll();
};
```

But nothing changes - all floors are still visible.  The floors set to visible = false don't disappear until renderAll() is called later on a window resize:

```
$(window).resize(setSize);
setSize();


function setSize(){
    viewportWidth = $(window).width();
    viewportHeight = $(window).height();
    $appContainer.css({ "width": viewportWidth, "height": viewportHeight}); 
    canvas.setDimensions({ width: viewportWidth, height: viewportHeight });
    if (canvas.building){
        canvas.building.center();
        canvas.building.scaleX = canvas.building.scaleY = (viewportWidth + viewportHeight) / (1920 + 1080);
        canvas.renderAll();
    }
}
```

but then they do disappear.  Why is one renderAll() working, and the other not?  I've tried wrapping the non-functioning renderAll() in a window.timeOut to see if a delay helps, but no luck.

Answer (score 5):

Ok - so I figured it out in the end: `building` is a group which appears to be getting cached by some internal fabric magic, and the cached version is being rendered instead of the updated version.  To render the updated version you have to do this

```
canvas.building.set('dirty', true);
canvas.renderAll();
```

Hope that helps someone on down the line.

EDIT

Turns out there's an easier solution still:

```
canvas.building.objectCaching = false
```

Comment: canvas.building.objectCaching = false
--> more information about this here: http://fabricjs.com/fabric-object-caching

Answer (score 2):

There is a new version that changed the format to:

```
canvas.requestRenderAll();
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to update (at least in the new version) object properties with `object.set({...})` or set `object.dirty = true` in order to make the cache system recognize the change in the object properties. Disabling cache might not be the best idea, it has been included for a reason. `canvas.requestRenderAll();` then works as intended.

Comment: It works for me, version 5.3.0

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in later versions:

```js
// for one canvas
myCanvas.objectCaching = false;

// for all canvas
fabric.Object.prototype.objectCaching = false;

// in both case it still needs to be re-rendered
myCanvas.renderAll();
```

ps: using version 4.2.0